# Why collection-item is not vertically center-aligned in collapsible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I am using materializecss framework. http://materializecss.com/

I am trying to contain links collection inside collapsible which is again inside the sidenav.

```
<body>

    <!-- Navbar goes here -->

    <!-- Page Layout here -->
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col s3">
        <!-- Grey navigation panel -->
            <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>String Operations</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body collection">
                        <!-- <div class="collection"> -->
                            <a href="#!" class="collection-item"> Alvin </a>
                            <a href="#!" class="collection-item"> Alvin </a>
                            <a href="#!" class="collection-item"> Alvin </a>
                            <a href="#!" class="collection-item"> Alvin </a>
                        <!-- </div> -->
                    </div> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col s9">
        <!-- Teal page content  -->
            work area
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

The problem is with the vertical alignment of the collection-item. I am not getting it in center. It is hanging at the top.[image: Vertical Alignment Problem].

I want to get that part "Alvin" vertically aligned in center.

Comment: Try make the a tag display block then vertical align center or margin auto 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `style code` in your head tag

```
<head>
   ...
   <style>
       .side-nav.fixed a{line-height: 50px;}
   </style>
   ...
</head>
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` only work when `line-height` has been defined. So you should add `line-height:` to `.collection-item`:

```
.collection-item {
    line-height: 2.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want to use the built-in facilities of MaterializeCSS framework. Can you help me with that?http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html http://materializecss.com/collections.html

Comment: ok. I just checked your code on jsfiddle. The problem is `padding` property of `collection-item` has been overrided by `padding` property of `.side-nav.fixed a`. So basically, You need to override it again in your css file. 
`.collection a.collection-item {padding: 10px 20px !important;}`